# Connected or disconnected

Tags: connectedness, path-connected

Let C(a,r) be the subset of R^2 given by C(a,r) = {(x,y) belongs to R^2| (x-a)^2 + y^2 = r^2}. 
Is C(0,1) union C(I,3) connected?

When we sketch both circles then C(0,1) comes out to be completely contained in C(1,3). We don't find any path between both circles. So these are disconnected.
But answer key says these are connected. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Why do you assume it is **you** who has gone wrong? The "answers at the back of the book" are usually included as an afterthought, and rarely are properly tested for quality....

Comment: Possibly the author was looking at the discs, not just the circles.

Comment: So it should be disconnected.

Comment: Yes, these subspaces are disconnected